# How to change structure of list items with JS to solve inline-block's generated space between them

Tags: javascript, html

In some of the ways to remove the space between list items when using `inline-block`, a way is to change this code:

```css
ul{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li{
  display: inline-block;
  background: #E43;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
}
li:hover{
  background: #F65;
  border-bottom: 2px solid dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

to this code:

```css
ul{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li{
  display: inline-block;
  background: #E43;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
}
li:hover{
  background: #F65;
  border-bottom: 2px solid dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<ul><li>
    Item 1</li><li>
    Item 2</li><li>
    Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

which works perfectly fine.

The question is how to change the first code's `li` structure to second code's using ***pure*** Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const iterator = document.createNodeIterator(ul, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, node => {
  if (node.parentElement.nodeName === 'UL') {
    return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
  }
  return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
});

const toBeRemoved = [];
let next = iterator.nextNode();
while(next) {
  toBeRemoved.push(next);
  next = iterator.nextNode();
}

toBeRemoved.forEach(n => n.remove());
```

```css
ul{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li{
  display: inline-block;
  background: #E43;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
}
li:hover{
  background: #F65;
  border-bottom: 2px solid dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

What this does is to create a `NodeIterator` to iterate over all the `text` nodes of the `UL` element and keep only those nodes that have the `UL` as their first ancestor.

Comment: Perfect and expandable. Thanks.